# Unable to run app on iPhone simulator suddenly

Tags: ios, xcode4, ios-simulator

My app has been running fine on iPhone simulator. I have hit an issue (discussed here: [Intermittent error accessing core data model / contacts database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923882/intermittent-error-accessing-core-data-model-contacts-database)) and now all of a sudden, it won't build and run on iPhone simulator. I have the following error:

```
Couldn't register com.yourcompany.XXX with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.(lldb)
```

Any thoughts? I have tried totally closing and resetting iPS as well as deleting the app and reinstalling but to no avail.

Very frustrating!!!

Comment: force quit your iphone simulator and once againg run your app. it's a bug

Comment: i always check the Activity Monitor to make sure the simulator is totally killed before restarting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens quite a lot for me, especially during frequent restarts of the simulated app. I tracked it down to (at least sometimes) a race condition or deadlock when the simulated app is shutting down and a new one is starting up.

1. Quitting the simulator usually work
2. If that does not help, restart Xcode
3. Sometimes processes may linger and **restarting the Mac** is ususally the quickest way to recover (although clever use of the `killall` command can salvage the situation if it is really inconvenient to restart).

Answer (score 2):

Reset your iphone simulator and clean up your xcode project.

Type

```
apple-alt-shift-k
```

in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Quit the iPhone simulator and run it again.

Comment: tried that. I had to completely reset the mac, Xcode, iPS and reset all settings. Finally worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Quit the simulator and xcode.Also delete the app from your simulator.... and if it does not work goto target setting and change something like name of app in bundle identifier . and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You are using Core Data. So its possible you changed the dataModel and `NSManagedObject` class is changed. So it will crash until you delete application from simulator and run your project again..

Comment: Wow - what's it like where you are Steve? ;)

Comment: Sorry mate? Did not get you.. :-|

Comment: anonymous is referring to your image/avatar. Seems to look like someone we all can recognize.