# Issue calling ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, abaddressbook

Has anyone had issues with this code...

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID (addressBook,recordID);
```

I have had major issues with this so far. I have previously posted this question [Intermittent error accessing core data model / contacts database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923882/intermittent-error-accessing-core-data-model-contacts-database)

However, I have now tracked it down to this method returning a NULL value despite there being legitimate addressBook and recordID values.

Any idea of why this might be happening?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer in case it helps others...

It turns out the issue was memory related. I have created an addressBook with: ABAddressBookCreate(). This was happening inside a loop so was being created over and over again. The solution was to move the creation outside of the loop and balance with CFRelease(addressBook); command.

Hope this helps others!!

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully done a addressbook with add,edit and delete the record from the contact list.there is no such type of error comes. put this in .h file...

```
ABRecordID 
recordID;
```

put following code in the

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
 recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);
 NSLog(@"Record id is %d",recordID);
}
```

if You getting the reoord id in that then i think there would be no such problem occours.
    Lets try ...